# oracle update with case statement issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am trying to execute following Update statement

```
UPDATE rebate_admin.PRODUCT_REBATE_ITEM_RULE_GROUP SET rule_priority_Nbr =  
CASE 
WHEN ( rule_priority_Nbr = 3) THEN (rule_priority_Nbr+1) 
WHEN ( rule_priority_Nbr = 4 ) THEN (rule_priority_Nbr-1) 
END
WHERE  DEFAULT_RULE_IND = 1 AND ACTIVE_IND= 1 AND RULE_PRIORITY_NBR NOT IN (9999999900, 1) 
AND PRODUCT_REBATE_DETAIL_SEQ IN (843 )
```

It fails with error:

> Cannot update (%s) to NULL.

Comment: try adding this to where clause:  and rule_priority_Nbr in (3,4)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to update. You exclude explicitly the rows where RULE_PRIORITY_NBR is 1 or 9999999990, you include explicitly the rows where RULE_PRIORITY_NBR is 3 or 4... what about all the other possible values? Clearly there are other values (which are updated to NULL, which leads to the error).

Comment: @tbone - assuming that is in fact the desired logic (which we don't know, it's for the OP to clarify).

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, I will change the IN clause. I understood the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a NOT NULL constraint on rule_priority_Nbr column. Your CASE statement doesnt have the ELSE, so when rule_priority_Nbr not 3 and not 4 the CASE will return null

Try like this for instance

```
UPDATE rebate_admin.PRODUCT_REBATE_ITEM_RULE_GROUP
 SET rule_priority_Nbr =
    CASE WHEN ( rule_priority_Nbr = 3) THEN (rule_priority_Nbr+1) 
        WHEN ( rule_priority_Nbr = 4 ) THEN (rule_priority_Nbr-1)
        ELSE rule_priority_Nbr 
    END 
WHERE DEFAULT_RULE_IND = 1 
AND ACTIVE_IND= 1 
AND RULE_PRIORITY_NBR NOT IN (9999999900, 1) 
AND PRODUCT_REBATE_DETAIL_SEQ IN (843 )
```

Comment: Bad idea! If in fact `rule_priority_nbr` can have other values (other than 3, 4, 999999990 and 1), then your solution will update it to itself. That may seem harmless, but is still generates UNDO and REDO. UPDATE statements should be written in such a way that ONLY the rows that really need to be updated are updated. tbone showed how to do that in a Comment under the original post.